# Upload / Import to GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, data, import, boundless-suite

Can I upload a shapefile to the GeoServer Import Data page, or does it only import data locally on the server?  When I click Browse to select the data to import, it seems to only browse the server filesystem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot upload a shapefile which resides on your own computer, into a *remote* GeoServer, no matter you use `GeoServer Layer Importer` or by adding a `Vector Data Source` (such as a `ShapeFile` or a `Directory of Spatial Files`).

The shapefile must to reside in the `data` directory, on the GeoServer machine or on an accessible `storage unit`. Therefore, you need to transfer your files from your computer to the *remote* GeoServer `data` directory, using any convenient method you have available. After the transfer is done, you may access the GeoServer *Import Data* interface from your own computer, and only browsing the *remote* server filesystem.

Remember that you will browse only the `data` directory on the GeoServer machine, and not the entire hard drive.